# virtualenvironmentwrapper: workon from bash script works only if source ~/.profile is called explicitly

Tags: bash

I am running a bash script that activates a virtualenvironment `workon myenv` on the raspberry pi and then runs a python script.

Unfortunately, the virtual environment cannot be activated, I get the error `workon: command not found`

I came across the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611394/virtualenv-workon-command-not-found/34611480

and added following lines to my ~/.profile (and also to `~/.bashrc`) file:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON='/usr/bin/python3'
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Then I've rebooted my raspberry pi but it only works if I add a line `source ~/.profile` in my bash script. So, it seems like the `.profile` is not loaded when a bash script is executed.

I am logging into my rpi via ssh.

Any clue what else I could try out?

Comment: Move the stuff you've added to `.profile` into `.bash_profile` (that one runs whenever a shell is started).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc) question which explains the difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile.

> X11 will look at your .bashrc while a "regular" Terminal will look at .bash_profile

So you will need to use .bash_profile in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, there is no `~/.bash_profile` on my pi, so I thought it would source `~/.profile` (as explained here: https://serverfault.com/questions/261802/what-are-the-functional-differences-between-profile-bash-profile-and-bashrc). I'll give it a try.

Comment: unfortunately it is not working, ~/.bash_profile is getting loaded but for some reason `workon` remains unfound.

Comment: @FrodeAkselsen Can you try adding `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH variable?

e.g. in `~/.bash_profile`, add this line at the beginning:
`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

You will need to either load `~/.bash_profile` or restart your shell before changes are loaded, by the way. It doesn't exist by default either, but don't worry - if it is created it will get used.

Comment: This could be helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928555/virtualenv-workon-command-not-found/49386113

Comment: /usr/local/bin is already in PATH, I've run the script and printed it out

Answer (score 0):

The trick I found is to add the following line on top of the script

> source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you said `add the following line`, but you presented two lines ... please format your snippet as code so that it shows up correctly